# How can you go back to your old ubuntu os from an upgrade pop os without using usb , cd , dvd and so on ..?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade

**Some time ago, I upgraded my OS to pop os, after days of doing that I needed to use some ubuntu software and OS, so I had the problem of not being able to go back without reinstalling the new ubuntu.**

Comment: That is not an upgrade. That is a replacement. You really should reinstall using an USB. There is a method where you download an ISO, put it in a 2.5 Gb partition and boot from that. Is that an option?

Comment: Unless you have a backup of Ubuntu from before "upgrading" it to POP OS, you can't. But can't you just install thee needed software in POP ?

Comment: I think 1 way might be to replace all the sources back to Ubuntu and have it do an upgrade. RISKY. As with any of these: make a backup or store your personal files on a diff.partition you mount and do not format.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*  found in the on-topic link)

Answer (score 3):

"Upgrading" to Pop OS is an impossibility - PopOS is a different Operating System than Ubuntu.  It may be ubuntu *based* but it is a unique system.

To 'go back' to plain Ubuntu you need to do a complete reinstall of Ubuntu.  There is no alternative as you cannot 'revert' switching OSes.

Comment: That's not entirely true. I've successfully converted existing ubuntu installation to pop-os by adding the repository, switching from grub to systemd-boot, and reinstalling some packages. Mainly pop-desktop and some system profiles. Yes, it's a hybrid and clean installation is better. Just sayin'.

Comment: @DaliborFilus there's a difference between a *hybrid* and a direct upgrade that OP was asking about in 2021

Answer (score 0):

I do make a bootable clone regularly, in particular just BEFORE upgrading (or of course using a new system), so if there is an immediate problem (like no Wifi), I have a chance to go back.

However, I had to make my own program to do this cleanly and quickly and also this does not protect from bugs that I see only after I have made a new clone.